# Is it possible to add "position level" to career profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

The only place where someone can add a preferred position level (jr., sr., management, etc) looks like the description. It would be beneficial to be able to use a drop-down (or taxonomy?) to say "I am looking to be a Jr. level employee" or "I expect to be the CEO".

If this already exists, I would like instructions on how to go about updating my profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the match preferences button on the matches tab at https://stackoverflow.com/jobs.

[image: Match Preferences]

This pops up a modal that allows you to specify what level of position you're interested in:

[image: Match Preferences Dialog]

In the near future this will be used to send out alerts so you'll get jobs matching your preferences by email. It will also be used in our employer-facing candidate search product to better surface candidates that match a particular job.